# Gradient buttons using only CSS

Tags: html, css, button

Is it possible to create this kind of button (with 3 states and variable width) completely with CSS3? Or at least avoid having images for every button?

[image: Buttons]

ok with cssbuttongenerator and jsfiddle i'm at this point: http://jsfiddle.net/Wdzje/ but its still not quite yet where i wanna be (color,border)! can someone help me out? Also the actve state isnt ready yet

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: You're going to need some HTML if you want your button to be interactive.

Comment: ...assuming you don't care about IE.

Comment: Please ask specific question on SO. You can google CSS3 buttons and find a million tutorials. Try posting your current html/css and then someone can help you implement it.

Comment: ok with cssbuttongenerator and jsfiddle i'm at this point:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wdzje/
but its still not quite yet where i wanna be (color,border)!
can someone help me out? also the active state isnt ready yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, there are numerous resources which help you achieve this. Check out http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/

Or expand upon this:

Button:

```
<a href="#" class="myButton">my button</a>
```

CSS

```
.myButton {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
background-color:#ededed;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
display:inline-block;
color:#777777;
font-family:arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:6px 24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}

.myButton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
background-color:#dfdfdf;
}

.myButton:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
```

Comment: No problem @kritop. Don't forget to mark your question as answered.

Comment: @JustinTurner, your answer is incomplete. He had asked for a button with 3 states. Yours is just a button.

Comment: @Aniket you are correct. I will post the updated, more elaborate, solution. However, the link provided provides further examples.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's possible.

you can use the css3 properties like radius, gradient, text shadow, box shadow to create something like the button you want..

look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLVLJ/

Here's the markup just in case the link dies:

```
<div class="button">
    button!
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.button {
    border: 1px solid #696;
    padding: 60px 0;
    text-align: center; width: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
    background: #EEFF99;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
    background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this - http://css3button.net/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your button with 3 working states using CSS3.

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/QZTP4/)

### The simple HTML

```
<button>
    I am a button!
</button>
```

### And here is the CSS

```
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    background: #32CD32;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#32CD32), to(#32AB32));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#32CD32, #32AB32);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#32CD32, #32AB32);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#32CD32, #32AB32);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#32CD32, #32AB32);
    background: linear-gradient(#32CD32, #32AB32);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
button:hover {
    background: #32AB32;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#32AB32), to(#32CD32));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #32CD32);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #32CD32);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #32CD32);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #32CD32);
    background: linear-gradient(#32AB32, #32CD32);
}
button:active {
    background: #329932;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#32AB32), to(#329932));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #329932);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #329932);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #329932);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#32AB32, #329932);
    background: linear-gradient(#32AB32, #329932);
}
```